# How to plot measurement-matrice

Tags: python, matrix, plot

I have finished my maesurements for my thesis and now I want to plot the matrice of pressure-combinations I measured. I would have different end-pressures for one suction-pressure, so for example:

```
1_bar = np.array([1, 2, 3])
2_bar = np.array([2, 3])
3_bar = np.array([])
4_bar = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
5_bar = np.array([1])
6_bar = np.array([])
7_bar = np.array([1, 2])
```

What I want is a plot that looks like this:
[image: Plot of measurment-matrice]

Basically i dont know how to create a matrice of this kind and then how to plot it. I hope someone can has the time to help me, I know this is a fairly basic question.

With kind regards and thank you in advance

Comment: Is this how you actually stored these data? (Why?) Wouldn't a dictionary or pandas dataframe be a better choice? How, in its current form, did you store the information that you have the arrays `1_bar`, `2_bar`, ..., `7_bar` or is it always these seven arrays with these names?

Comment: Hello Mr. T, I was not sure if I knew the best way to store my data. As you said, a dictionary would have been the best option. The answer below worked for me, but I appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `matplotlib` for that and try a scatter plot. e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


bar_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
bar_2 = np.array([2, 3])
bar_3 = np.array([])
bar_4 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
bar_5 = np.array([1])
bar_6 = np.array([])
bar_7 = np.array([1, 2])

measurements = {1: bar_1, 2: bar_2, 3: bar_3, 4: bar_4, 5: bar_5, 6: bar_6, 7: bar_7}

x, y = [], []
for pressure, measurement in measurements.items():
    for value in measurement:
        x.append(pressure)
        y.append(value)

plt.scatter(x, y, marker='+')
plt.show()
```

BTW it would be probably helpful if you save the data in a `dict` right away. This way it is more generic and you can better work with it.